# Android Facebook-SDK setup does not work as intended

Tags: android, facebook

according to: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#sample
I did the following (short form):
-get a clone of the git repo
-start a new android project using "Create project from existing source"
-referenced to "~/facebook-android-sdk/facebook"

after this the newly created project cannot compile because it has no manifest. After copying it into this project manually, it doesn't even have the .java files and other resources.

After copying all the stuff manually it now does work, but is there anything in the "normal" workflow according to the tutorial I did oversee? Or does anyone know why it does not work as intended using "Create project from existing source"?

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way you can go with is to create the Jar file out of the facebook-sdk project you downloaded. This can be done by exporting the facebook project as Jar from eclipse.

Then you can add this jar to your own project where you want to integrate facebook.

This way your code will be clean and manageable too.

Comment: this might be, but with the described steps in the tutorial I don't even get a compilable project.

Answer (score 0):

you see the file /tests/default.properties facebook project use as a library.then i think you understand all process.Please follow this instruction
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#sample